# DETAIL: Role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am running postgresql this way (according this instruction https://hevodata.com/learn/docker-postgresql/ )

```
docker run --name postgres3 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres1 -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust -p 5432:5432 -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

than trying to connect and it fails with following log:

```
└─$ docker logs 99691c70698b

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2023-06-09 13:58:38.652 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-06-09 13:58:38.653 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-06-09 13:58:38.653 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-06-09 13:58:38.662 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-06-09 13:58:38.670 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-06-09 13:58:04 UTC
2023-06-09 13:58:38.677 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-06-09 13:58:43.492 UTC [33] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2023-06-09 13:58:52.636 UTC [34] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2023-06-09 13:58:52.636 UTC [34] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2023-06-09 14:03:30.404 UTC [44] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2023-06-09 14:03:30.404 UTC [44] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2023-06-09 14:03:38.766 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2023-06-09 14:03:38.783 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.006 s, sync=0.003 s, total=0.018 s; sync files=2, longest=0.002 s, average=0.002 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2023-06-09 14:19:14.076 UTC [76] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2023-06-09 14:21:32.667 UTC [82] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2023-06-09 14:21:32.667 UTC [82] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

What am I doing wrong? What is "Role postgres"? How to properly install containerized Postgres 15.x ?

**UPD:**
Postgres was installed by "docker pull postgres"

Comment: 1) The error is straight forward the `postgres` role(user) does not exist in that Postgres instance. 2) How was Postgres installed? **Add information as update to question**.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  Postgres was installed by "docker pull postgres" . Does the "role" and "username" means the same in Postgres?

Comment: 1) For detailed explanation of  `role` vs `user` read [Create Role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) and [Create User](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html).  In the distant past (Postgres 8-) there was user and group, but they have been consolidated into `role`. 2) In general Postgres installs create a system user `postgres` and a database role `postgres`. It would seem the process you are using does not. You will need to dig more into what the install is actually doing.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I just followed this instruction https://hevodata.com/learn/docker-postgresql/

Comment: "PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization", so it found an already existing database and used it.  So all your -e arguments were ignored.  You are at the mercy of however that existing database was configured, which we have no way of knowing.

Comment: I'm guessing it is in the `docker pull postgres`. That the image being pulled is using a different role then usual when creating the database instance. I don't use Docker so I am not going to be much help on that end.

Comment: As @jjanes noted the Postgres server has already been set up. When you did the initial run did you use something different for `-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres1`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes I did, but I want to tell that it doesn't work as described here https://hevodata.com/learn/docker-postgresql/

Comment: Well if you supplied a different `POSTGRES_USER=` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD=` during the initial run then that is what the Postgres `initdb` will use to set the database superuser. It also means you will need to use those values in the subsequent runs, until such time as you do a `CREATE ROLE <some_role>` to make new roles. For full details see docs at [Postgres Docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it doesn't matter which values I use on initial start, psql doesn't work, server doesn't accept password. Please take a look at log https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/9029dc77e92bd22083a71041c805c907

Comment: To me it looks like you are  running `psql --username=postgres --dbname=postgres` at your terminal outside the Docket container. If so the error message *connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory* is correct as the Postgres server is not running on the Docker host.  You will need to connect to whatever port the Docker container is set up to translate the Postgres server port to. I'm going to guess `5432`, so `psql --username=postgres --dbname=postgres -p 5432` .

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have re-ran Postgresql with following command "docker run --name postgresql2 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpwd4habr -p 5432:5432 -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres"  but "psql --username=postgres --dbname=postgres -p 5432" running outside the docker container still give the same error

Comment: My mistake you should add  `-h postgresql2`. Or use the Docker command shown here [Postgres Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) `docker run -it --rm --network some-network postgres psql -h some-postgres -U postgres` with the appropriate values for your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an "-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres" option. It run well without it (default user is postgres). Initial start must be without "-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres"